# YUV player in HTML

Tags: html, video

At the moment i have a webApi that provides me a videostream (retrieves from the disk the mp4 file and sends back to the requester a video stream).
In the html i use the following code to display the video:

```
<video id="video" class="dtm-video-element" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto">       
    <source src="/api/Sample" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

I have a new request where i have to render also a yuv format video. The problem that i am facing is that the video tag from html is not able to recognize the yuv format.

Can someone point me to a html yuv compatible player ?

Comment: As far as I know SourceBuffer of MSE only allowes to process Media Segments, which are sequences of bytes that contain packetized & timestamped media data (mp4). In case of yuv this is not true :(
It is still quite ineresting question But from my experience with yuv players the rendering and the amount of data to process is quite challenging even using native c/c++ aps. I don't think that using a web browser is a good idea

Comment: You can "encode" the video into h.264 I_PCM macroblocks (which are really just yuv) than wrap that in an MP4 fragment then play with MSE. But you need to check if it's yuv420 yuv422 or yuv444 and make sure the browser will play it.